# Ruby find all Constants

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby so sorry if it's a simple question.
I want to open a ruby file and search all constants, but I don't know the right regular expression.

Here is my simplified code:

```
def findconst()
 filename = @path_main  
 k= {}
 akonstanten = []
 k[:konstanten] = akonstanten


 if (File.exists?(filename))
  file = open(filename, "r")
   while (line = file.gets)
    if (line =~  ????)
     k[:konstanten] << line
    end
   end
 end 
end
```

Comment: To do it reliably you need to parse the code into AST, and this is not something you can do with regexes.

Comment: so i cant parse for all expression written in caps?

Comment: does your file simply contain a known set of classes/modules ?

Comment: i want to parse several files, just to know which constants, functions ect they contain.

Comment: @user1878703: you get all words that are in caps, but what about this one `MAGIC_STRING = "This is a word in CAPS"`? How many constants do you see here?

Comment: mhh i know what u mean, maybe i search for all words in caps with    /^\s* Words in Caps

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting what was added upon load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737792/getting-what-was-added-upon-load)

Comment: mhh i try to get this work but as i said im new to ruby so its hard to understand but i´ll try

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Ripper](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ripper/rdoc/Ripper.html) library to extract the tokens.

For example, this code will return you constants and methods names for the file

```
A = "String" # Comment
B = <<-STR
  Yet Another String
STR

class C
  class D
    def method_1
    end
    def method_2
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
require "ripper"

tokens = Ripper.lex(File.read("file.rb"))

pp tokens.group_by { |x| x[1] }[:on_ident].map(&:last)
pp tokens.group_by { |x| x[1] }[:on_const].map(&:last)

# => ["method_1", "method_2"]
# => ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
```

Answer (score 0):

As Sergio Says searching for words with Caps won't just give you constants but if it's good enough it's good enough.

The regexpression you are looking for is something like

```
if (line =~ /[^a-z][A-Z]/)
```

Which says match any capital that is not preceded by a lower case letter.  Of course this will only count one per line so you might like to consider tokenising the stream and working on tokens, not lines.

Comment: this isnt working for me it still find words like Controller, i have to use ruby 1.8.7 if its important.

Comment: `Controller` *is* a constant (assuming that it is a variable identifier, of course), since it starts with a capital letter.

Comment: the word was maybe not the best example but it outputs me all words which start with a capital, i want only words like THIS or EXAMPLE